# Expression Binding for Property in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to set the property of a control using another control's property. In my case, I have one `<sap.m.Select>` and a `<sap.m.Input>`. The `visible` of `<sap.m.Input>` will depend on the `selectedItem` of the `<sap.m.Select>`. IMO, there is an available approach using Expression binding in XML View but I don't know how. Any suggestion?

Comment: [There was an attempt](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/pull/727) to solve this kind of problems without using a model. But the idea seems to be abandoned.. :\ Right now, we've to use client-side models for this as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two way binding so that both properties are binding expressions over the same property in the model.

So you can create a JSON model for example and put there a property called `selectedItem`. The binding of the properties should be: on select `selectedItem={mymodel>selectedItem}` and on input `visible={parts: [{path: "mymodel>selectedItem"}], formatter: function (selectedItem) {<your manipulation>} }`.

You can do that with JavaScript and with XML view. In XML view you should reference to a formatter method in the controller.